# Conditional object in JavaScript for json post

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a function named update that takes some options and post to my php using $.post:

```
 function update(options){
   $.post('update.php',{update: options}, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
     // debug stuff from php
   });
 }
```

I call my function as follows:

```
 update({'id': id, 'option': val});
```

What I would like to know is how I can make a conditional inside the options? For example:

```
 var option = $(this).attr('class') == 'check' ? 'check' : 'ok'; // assuming option is ok

 update({'id': id, 'ok': val}); // instead of option

 update({'id': id, option: val}); // i want to have the conditional
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access Javascript objects in the same way that you access arrays. This syntax supports dynamic property names/keys.

```
options[variable] = 'value';
```

Example:

```
var x = 'customProperty'
,   y = {}
;

y.x = 12; //y.x = 12
y[x] = 11; //y.customProperty = 11... same as y['customProperty'] = 11
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CoryDanielson/Dugdd/

Comment: He wants `option` be a dynamic key I think

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you set your object as such:

```
var x = {};
```

Then assign the exact property you want

```
var prop_name = $(this).attr('class') == 'check' ? 'check' : 'ok';
x[prop_name] = YOUR_VALUE;
```

Comment: If you're asking to put the actual condition itself inside the JSON string, the answer is "no" you can't do that because the condition expression will be evaluated into its boolean result (true or false) and will always return the value specified by each part of your ternary statement.